# How can I generate all Entity Framework classes with Pascal Case notation on properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an Oracle database that has columns named in the following way :  CREATED_BY, EMPLOYEE_FIRST_NAME,

When my Entity Framework classes are generated, I want the column's associated properties to look like : CreatedBy, EmployeeFirstName, etc...

Is there a way to do it without having to go edit every property manually ?

Comment: I know Resharper is able to recognize and parse the FOO_BAR_BAZ convention, as well as camelcase. I've never tried to use re#er to script this type of code transformation across several files at a time, but it's great at changing one identifier at a time, and it's great at finding them. You could start there.

Answer (score 2):

It actually might not be about C# code at all. If you are using Oracle then I assume it is either ModelFirst or DatabaseFirst approach. In this case the code is generated based on the CSDL. If you convert property names stuff will break since EF will not be able to find types and properties that correspond to the property names in the CSDL. In addition to that as soon as the code will be regenerated (e.g. you save your model) you will lose all your changes. What you need to do is to change the names of the properties in the CSDL (the conceptual part of the EDMX) and then MSL (the mapping part of EDMX) accordingly. So you are looking actually at processing Xml. I think it can be done relatively easily with Xslt or Linq to Xml if you are familiar with these technologies. If you do this correctly the code generator/T4 template should generate code with the names you provided. Alternatively, you can change names in the EF designer manually but it will be a lot of work.

Answer (score 2):

Around 2 weeks ago, I was tasked with getting rid of Linq Connect as our Data provider to using EF for our ORM operations. Well, as well all know it, things are never easy when Microsoft and Oracle are involved, as they don’t play well together. It was up to the savvy developer to find a solution for Pascal Casing and Pluralization, so that the Entities generated from the Oracle database matched our standards. We didn't want table names with underscores to show up on our Models. It took a little bit of thought and development to finally come to a good solution. The end result was manipulating the EDMX file and then running the T4 templates to make the magic happen. Our end result converted all the entities and their properties to Pascal casing. It also converted all the Stored functions to Pascal casing. Navigation properties to collection were all also pluralized.
Here are the steps and the code snippet to follow. Hope this helps some one in the coding community and you can always reach out to me at seafarer_007  on twitter with helpful comments or suggestions.
Here it is:
1. Generate the EDMX using the EF Data Model item. I used EF 5.0 in Visual Studio 2012.
2. Write  a console app that manipulates the EDMX and the designer files. I have added references to both in the App Config.
3. That should be it, and you will have Pascal cased and Pluralized entities. You can always tweak the Pascal case method to your desires.
4. I tested the code on Visual Studio 2012 and EF 5.0.
5. Caveat : Works with only a single worded namespace without dots, basically you can’t have OrgName.DeptName.Namespace for the Model, it will only handle OrgName, however, you can tweak the Pascal Casing Method to resolve that.

Console Application code below:

static void Main(string[] args)
        {

```
        string pathFile = string.Empty;
        string designFile = string.Empty;


        //EDMX File location
        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EDMX"] != null)
        {
            pathFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EDMX"].ToString();
        }

        //Designer location for EF 5.0
        if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EDMXDiagram"] != null)
        {
            designFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EDMXDiagram"].ToString();
        }





        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(pathFile);


        const string CSDLNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm";
        const string MSLNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/mapping/cs";

        XElement csdl = xdoc.Descendants(XName.Get("Schema", CSDLNamespace)).First();
        XElement msl = xdoc.Descendants(XName.Get("Mapping", MSLNamespace)).First();



        #region CSDL
        foreach (var entitySet in csdl.Element(XName.Get("EntityContainer", CSDLNamespace)).Elements(XName.Get("EntitySet", CSDLNamespace)))
        {
            entitySet.Attribute("Name").Value = PascalCase(entitySet.Attribute("Name").Value);
            entitySet.Attribute("EntityType").Value = PascalCase(entitySet.Attribute("EntityType").Value);
        }
        foreach (var associationSet in csdl.Element(XName.Get("EntityContainer", CSDLNamespace)).Elements(XName.Get("AssociationSet", CSDLNamespace)))
        {
            foreach (var end in associationSet.Elements(XName.Get("End", CSDLNamespace)))
            {
                end.Attribute("EntitySet").Value = PascalCase(end.Attribute("EntitySet").Value);
            }
        }

        foreach (var funtionSet in csdl.Element(XName.Get("EntityContainer", CSDLNamespace)).Elements(XName.Get("FunctionImport", CSDLNamespace)))
        {

            funtionSet.Attribute("Name").Value = PascalCase(funtionSet.Attribute("Name").Value);

        }

        foreach (var entityType in csdl.Elements(XName.Get("EntityType", CSDLNamespace)))
        {
            entityType.Attribute("Name").Value = PascalCase(entityType.Attribute("Name").Value);

            foreach (var key in entityType.Elements(XName.Get("Key", CSDLNamespace)))
            {
                foreach (var propertyRef in key.Elements(XName.Get("PropertyRef", CSDLNamespace)))
                {
                    propertyRef.Attribute("Name").Value = PascalCase(propertyRef.Attribute("Name").Value);
                }
            }

            foreach (var property in entityType.Elements(XName.Get("Property", CSDLNamespace)))
            {
                property.Attribute("Name").Value = PascalCase(property.Attribute("Name").Value);
            }

            foreach (var navigationProperty in entityType.Elements(XName.Get("NavigationProperty", CSDLNamespace)))
            {
                navigationProperty.Attribute("Name").Value = PascalCase(navigationProperty.Attribute("Name").Value, true, true); 
            }

        }
        foreach (var association in csdl.Elements(XName.Get("Association", CSDLNamespace)))
        {
            foreach (var end in association.Elements(XName.Get("End", CSDLNamespace)))
            {
                end.Attribute("Type").Value = PascalCase(end.Attribute("Type").Value);
            }               

            foreach(var refs in association.Elements(XName.Get("ReferentialConstraint", CSDLNamespace)))
            {

                foreach (var pri in refs.Elements(XName.Get("Principal", CSDLNamespace)))
                {

                    foreach (var proref in pri.Elements(XName.Get("PropertyRef", CSDLNamespace)))
                    {

                        proref.Attribute("Name").Value = PascalCase(proref.Attribute("Name").Value);
                    }

                }

                foreach (var pri in refs.Elements(XName.Get("Dependent", CSDLNamespace)))
                {

                    foreach (var proref in pri.Elements(XName.Get("PropertyRef", CSDLNamespace)))
                    {

                        proref.Attribute("Name").Value = PascalCase(proref.Attribute("Name").Value);
                    }

                }


            }



        }
        #endregion

        #region MSL

        foreach (var entitySetMapping in msl.Element(XName.Get("EntityContainerMapping", MSLNamespace)).Elements(XName.Get("EntitySetMapping", MSLNamespace)))
        {
            entitySetMapping.Attribute("Name").Value = PascalCase(entitySetMapping.Attribute("Name").Value);

            foreach (var entityTypeMapping in entitySetMapping.Elements(XName.Get("EntityTypeMapping", MSLNamespace)))
            {
                entityTypeMapping.Attribute("TypeName").Value = PascalCase(entityTypeMapping.Attribute("TypeName").Value);
                foreach
                (var scalarProperty in
                (entityTypeMapping.Element(XName.Get("MappingFragment", MSLNamespace))).Elements(XName.Get("ScalarProperty", MSLNamespace))
                )
                {
                    scalarProperty.Attribute("Name").Value = PascalCase(scalarProperty.Attribute("Name").Value);
                }

            }
        }
        foreach (var associationSetMapping in msl.Element(XName.Get("EntityContainerMapping", MSLNamespace)).Elements(XName.Get("AssociationSetMapping", MSLNamespace)))
        {
            foreach (var endProperty in associationSetMapping.Elements(XName.Get("EndProperty", MSLNamespace)))
            {
                foreach (var scalarProperty in endProperty.Elements(XName.Get("ScalarProperty", MSLNamespace)))
                {
                    scalarProperty.Attribute("Name").Value = PascalCase(scalarProperty.Attribute("Name").Value);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var functionSetMapping in msl.Element(XName.Get("EntityContainerMapping", MSLNamespace)).Elements(XName.Get("FunctionImportMapping", MSLNamespace)))
        {
            functionSetMapping.Attribute("FunctionImportName").Value = PascalCase(functionSetMapping.Attribute("FunctionImportName").Value);
        }
        #endregion

        xdoc.Save(pathFile);


        XmlDocument designXml = new XmlDocument();

        designXml.Load(designFile);      


        XmlNamespaceManager dsMan = new XmlNamespaceManager(designXml.NameTable);
        dsMan.AddNamespace("edmx", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx");
        dsMan.AddNamespace("d", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edmx");


        #region Designer

        XmlNodeList entitySet1 = designXml.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//d:Diagrams", dsMan);

        foreach (XmlNode xn in entitySet1)
        {

            foreach (XmlElement xp in xn.ChildNodes)
            {

                foreach (XmlElement z in xp.ChildNodes)
                {

                    if (z.Attributes[0].Name == "EntityType")
                    {

                        z.Attributes[0].Value = PascalCase(z.Attributes[0].Value.ToString(), true);

                    }


                }

            }


        }

        designXml.Save(designFile);


        #endregion

    }

    #region Pluralization


    public static string Pluralize(string name)
    {

   return System.Data.Entity.Design.PluralizationServices.PluralizationService.CreateService(new CultureInfo("en-US")).Pluralize(name);
    }



    #endregion



    #region Pascal Casing

    public static string PascalCase(StructuralType type, bool sanitizeName = true)
    {
        if (type == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return PascalCase(type.Name, sanitizeName);
    }


    public static string PascalCase(EdmMember member, bool sanitizeName = true)
    {
        if (member == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return PascalCase(member.Name, sanitizeName);
    }

    public static string PascalCase(string name, bool sanitizeName = true, bool pluralize = false)
    {

       // if pascal case exists
       // exit function

        Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^[A-Z][a-z]+(?:[A-Z][a-z]+)*$");

        string pascalTest = name;

        if (name.Contains("."))
        {
            string[] test  = new string[]{};
            test = name.Split('.');

            if(rgx.IsMatch(test[1].ToString()))
            {
                return name;
            }

        }
        else
        {

            if (rgx.IsMatch(name))
            {
                return name;
            }

        }

        //Check for dot notations in namespace

        bool contains = false;
        string[] temp = new string[] { };
        var namespc = string.Empty;

        if (name.Contains("."))
        {
            contains = true;
            temp = name.Split('.');
            namespc = temp[0];

        }

        if (contains)
        {
            name = temp[1];
        }

        name = name.ToLowerInvariant();

        string result = name;
        bool upperCase = false;

        result = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
        {
            if (name[i] == ' ' || name[i] == '_')
            {
                upperCase = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (i == 0 || upperCase)
                {
                    result += name[i].ToString().ToUpperInvariant();
                    upperCase = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    result += name[i];
                }
            }
        }


        if (contains)
        {


            result = namespc.ToString() + "." + result;



        }

        if (pluralize)
        {
            result = Pluralize(result);
        }


        return result;
    }
    #endregion
```